# Interactive Shiny or Observable JS Slide in Quarto Presentation?

Tags: r, observable, rstudio, quarto

I am making a quarto presentation illustrating different features and the benefits to making presentations in quarto for colleagues. I can't seem to find a simple example demonstrating an interactive slide with a shiny app or Observable JS.

Is it possible to create an interactive graph from either of the two in a quarto presentation? Or in both scenarios do they need to be hosted on a server in the background and embedded in the presentation? If not, could you please provide the code for a simple interactive figure I could include in the presentation?

Comment: See the oficial example in the Quarto documentation: https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/demo/#/interactive-slides-1 
From what I gather, the Quarto document runs on the server side automatically.